# Can iptables drop all packets with identical source and destination ports?

Tags: linux, iptables

I have recently encountered some malicious TCP traffic that came in with a destination of port 80, and also with a source port of 80. This traffic is obviously invalid, and would be so for any application that I can think of, as the source port should be both random and in the ephemeral range. While dropping packets with source ports below the ephemeral range or with a source and destination port of 80 is easy enough, I would like to take this a step further and block ALL traffic where the source and destination ports are identical.

Is it possible to drop all packets with iptables where the source and destination ports are identical, without creating thousands of rules? If so, is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it without creating one rule per port.

Also, at least for port 53, the primary and secondary DNS computers communicate between each other over port 53, source and destination. I think that DHCP does the same thing. This is because such servers open a port and use that socket to send data. Thus the source has the same port as the destination.

Note that it probably isn't a big issue for ports larger than 1023. So you wouldn't want to block more than that.

Further, all of those should automatically be blocked anyway since your firewall has only the ports of the services you offer opened, right? i.e. if you offer HTTP & HTTPS, you would only open port 80 and 443.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m tcp --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Any other combo will be blocked by the second rule or change the input table policy to DROP and then you don't even need that second rule:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

***WARNING:** this is hardly a complete example, you'll need to open the firewall for `lo` and established/related connections to a minimum.*

It can be difficult to setup your firewall without getting blocked. Make sure that you either have access through a system other than just SSH (i.e. console over HTTP like many ISPs offer now a day) or make triple sure that SSH will always be available (open the port before all the other fancy things you're adding to your firewall).